# How to convert a Amazon SageMaker model to a Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a model using Amazon SageMaker and I need to convert the model into a Tensorflow model. Is there any way it can be achieved?

Comment: I don't understand the question; amazon sagemaker can be used to train tensorflow models: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/tf.html

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Yes, I am aware that Amazon SageMaker can train Tensorflow models, however, I am looking for a way to convert a model build using SageMaker's built-in algorithm (for instance Linear Learner) into a Tensorflow model

Comment: Some of the Amazon SageMaker built-in algorithms are using Apache MXNet. There are some converters between libraries such as ONNX. Why exactly do you need the model to be in TF? If for serving, you can use MXNet serving.